# How do I find a traffic light with simple image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I want to implement simple traffic light detection algorithm in Python with help of OpenCV. Of course if we want to get high accuracy, we should use some pre-trained deep learning models, but now I want just simplest and not  comprehensive approach. Namely I know that traffic lights are (green, red , yellow), therefore I found following [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-color-detection-in-real-time-using-python-opencv/) which contains code about three color detection.

I know once again, that it is not an accurate method, just self learning. I have tested this code on one video. Here is a cropped frame from the corresponding [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYLgF.jpg):
[image]

After running my code, I got following image:
[image]

As you can see, the lowest part of the image is ignored and upper part is considered.

---

How can I adapt or change my code such that it should check whole image and detect  actual  traffic lights as well?
Should I resize the image to a lower resolution?
Should I use some other approach?

---

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
# Capturing video through webcam
live_video = cv2.VideoCapture("traffic_light.mp4")
# Start a while loop
while (1):
    # Reading the video from the
    # webcam in image frames
    _, imageFrame = live_video .read()

    # Convert the imageFrame in
    # BGR(RGB color space) to
    # HSV(hue-saturation-value)
    # color space
    hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(imageFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Set range for red color and
    # define mask
    red_lower = np.array([136, 87, 111], np.uint8)
    red_upper = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, red_lower, red_upper)

    # Set range for green color and
    # define mask
    green_lower = np.array([25, 52, 72], np.uint8)
    green_upper = np.array([102, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, green_lower, green_upper)

    # Set range for blue color and
    # define mask
    blue_lower = np.array([94, 80, 2], np.uint8)
    blue_upper = np.array([120, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, blue_lower, blue_upper)

    # Morphological Transform, Dilation
    # for each color and bitwise_and operator
    # between imageFrame and mask determines
    # to detect only that particular color
    kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8")

    # For red color
    red_mask = cv2.dilate(red_mask, kernal)
    res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(imageFrame, imageFrame,
                              mask=red_mask)

    # For green color
    green_mask = cv2.dilate(green_mask, kernal)
    res_green = cv2.bitwise_and(imageFrame, imageFrame,
                                mask=green_mask)

    # For blue color
    blue_mask = cv2.dilate(blue_mask, kernal)
    res_blue = cv2.bitwise_and(imageFrame, imageFrame,
                               mask=blue_mask)

    # Creating contour to track red color
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(red_mask,
                                           cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area > 300):
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            imageFrame = cv2.rectangle(imageFrame, (x, y),
                                       (x + w, y + h),
                                       (0, 0, 255), 2)

            cv2.putText(imageFrame, "Red Colour", (x, y),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0,
                        (0, 0, 255))

            # Creating contour to track green color
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(green_mask,
                                           cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area > 300):
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            imageFrame = cv2.rectangle(imageFrame, (x, y),
                                       (x + w, y + h),
                                       (0, 255, 0), 2)

            cv2.putText(imageFrame, "Green Colour", (x, y),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        1.0, (0, 255, 0))

    # Creating contour to track blue color
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blue_mask,
                                           cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area > 300):
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            imageFrame = cv2.rectangle(imageFrame, (x, y),
                                       (x + w, y + h),
                                       (255, 0, 0), 2)

            cv2.putText(imageFrame, "Blue Colour", (x, y),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        1.0, (255, 0, 0))

    # Program Termination
    cv2.imshow("Multiple Color Detection in Real-TIme", imageFrame)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        live_video  .release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

I am thinking about resizing of frames, but first I would like to listen your opinions. The main tricky part, I think, is located in the following code, since it tries to locate cursor in the specific contours determined by coordinates. How can I change it?

Comment: On your previous question, you were curious why it got a downvote. Note that this is a Q&A site, not a forum ([tour]), and we emphasize quality ([ask]). Part of that involves writing legibly (including capitalization of sentences and proper nouns), asking concrete questions, and avoiding conversational text like greetings and various other meta-commentary you tend to include. Please, [edit] your post and fix those issues, if you want it to be received positively.

Comment: Dear @DanMašek thank you for your comments. first  i am not native speaker and therefore  i might not be able to  pay attention to the capitalization of first letters  and so on, next about greetings -we are all humans, for me when i am posting a question  , i know that i am asking to people and my country -Georgia(Saqartvelo) is well known for  its  polite  and  warm  and kind people thereofre greetings is in my character and  lets dont underline those  words  as a negative words,  about question - it is concrete and everyone can    determine what is the main part and question from my post,

Comment: I understand, I'm not a native English speaker either. In fact, your command of English is way better than what I've seen some native speakers produce. Noone's going to nag you for a few mistakes, that can happen even to the best. However, if you completely give up on something as essential as proper capitalization (something that helps people understand the text), it can be taken as a sign of lack of effort. Think of it this way -- what would your English teacher say if you submitted an essay that looked like this post?

Comment: most probably  she or he might not know such better  that  try to fix it :D :D  it is joke of course, ok  thank you sir and  next time i will pay  more attention to the  grammar and  writting styles. by the  way about question - when i have  resized image and made it  a bit smaller, code started  to detect    traffic lights located  near  to the  bottom corner of the street.  but of course it detects a lot of  green,  red  and  yellow colors. so deep models i  think a only alternative method for higher accuracy result

Comment: Regarding the politeness bit -- yes, but this site is different from most. Like I said before, it's not a discussion forum, nor a help desk -- it's impersonal, as odd as that may seem. The sole goal is building a repository of questions useful to a wide audience, accompanied by correct answers. Unless you make some serious transgression, any voting is about the posts, not about your person. Think of it as contributing a page or two to a textbook.

Comment: @DanMašek i will do my best next time.thanks for your advices -if  we seperate those minor  mistakes from the question, you might agree that  question is very legitimate  and interesting right? so it  would somehow  contribute  page   in a good  way

Comment: I fixed the post up a little. Could you please try to provide an uncropped input image? Either try to lower the JPEG quality, or just post it directly to imgur and give us a link.

Comment: here is   imgur link for the original  big image(unfortunately i can't post because it is  more than 2 MB) https://imgur.com/K4BhTAw

Comment: here is correspoonding video link, i have uploaded video as well : https://imgur.com/Lkq72gJ

Comment: Excellent. Now it's much more useful, and there's my upvote. Well done on providing code that actually runs :) | Some nitpicks first. Minor, but `while (1)` would better be `while(True)`. | `_, imageFrame = live_video .read()` -- worse, since this makes the code crash when it reaches the end of video. Either test the first value in the tuple (a boolean you currently ignore) whether it's `True`, and if not, break the loop. Alternatively, test if `imageFrame` is not `None`. | Also, shouldn't you be looking for yellow, instead of blue?

Comment: yes actually i have added also  yellow fragment,  here is corresponding upper and low ranges : yellow_lower = np.array([22, 93, 0])
    yellow_upper = np.array([45, 255, 255])
    yellow_mask =cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, yellow_lower, yellow_upper)  , so maybe tommorow i will continue because my students have exam  so  in order  to  prepare for their  complain :D  i should be  well  asleep , tommorow  i will continue  and  post if anything new will be. thanks  for  today  advices  and help. good night sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251295/discussion-between-dan-masek-and-ai-researcher).

Comment: in computer vision, "focus", in combination with "camera", refers to how a lens produces an image on a sensor, and how the image is sharp only for a certain distance, and gets progressively blurrier for objects that are further away from that focal plane. using the word "focus" for "attention" is not at all obvious, but that seems to be what you want. if you want to find specific objects areas of the picture and continue working on those, we call that "regions of interest" (ROI).

Comment: the pictures in your post don't show any attempt to analyze a traffic light. the only output picture you show is of some facade and no traffic lights at all, so that can't possibly demonstrate any issue you might have in identifying traffic lights. -- assuming your code can find areas of red/yellow/green (traffic light), to find a traffic light, you'd now have to test if the correct three of such detections are on top of each other.

Comment: I'd recommend that you attempt to solve your task, or share your thoughts on approaches you can think of, or at least discuss the challenges you can't overcome on your own (which are they, what keeps you from overcoming them). an attempt is expected of you, and so is the research. see [ask]. this is important. don't think an increasing reputation score will shield you from valid criticism. if you're being vocal over your misplaced "expectations" of this place and the people giving you free time, that will also, to put it mildly, *not help*.

Comment: I would also point out that the red range of hues is around zero and on both sides of it. That is 0 to R1 and R2 to 180. You are only including the latter in your test above, so only testing for half of the possible red values.  If you measure your red stop light, most of it has a value of H=0, S=V=255 or 100%.  So your range of 136 to 180 is missing most of your red stop light which has hue=0.

Comment: For reference, see https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html and https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html where it says "For HSV, hue range is [0,179]"  180 should be the same as 0, but I am not sure how OpenCV handles the wrap around.

Comment: it doesn't handle any wraparound. the hue plane simply has values from 0 to 179, in the uint8 case. -- I would generally not recommend "opencv24"-anything sites. that stuff is a snapshot of what the official documentation was _several_ years ago.

Comment: i am here, so  @ChristophRackwitz which framework  would you  advice me?